# guice conditional module install

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have got below code in main class

```
public ABCImpl() {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new SomeModule());
    this.config = injector.getInstance(SomeConfig.class);
```

SomeModule has other modules in it installed like

```
public class SomeModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new SomeOtherModule());
        install(new AndAnotherModule());
    }
}
```

SomeOtherModule module belongs to some different jar and it has a provider implementation.

```
@ProvidesIntoOptional(ProvidesIntoOptional.Type.DEFAULT)
public XYZ getXYZ() {
    return new XYZ();
}
```

Now I want to override this default inside SomeModule or create a different module to be installed based on values in config

```
@ProvidesIntoOptional(ProvidesIntoOptional.Type.DEFAULT)
public XYZ getXYZDifferentWay() {
    return new XYZ(someparam);
}
```

How can I achieve this. My only goal is if some value on config is true then I should get different XYZ otherwise keep things as it is. This could be useful in cases where you need default resource connection but in local machine may be I can use mock resource.

Answer (score 3):

Literally just install them conditionally:

```
if (condition) {
  install(new SomeOtherModule());
} else {
  install(new AndAnotherModule());
}
```

Or, if you want `AndAnotherModule` to override the bindings in `SomeOtherModule`, use [`Modules.override`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/util/Modules.html):

```
Module module = new SomeOtherModule();
if (condition) {
  module = Modules.override(module).with(new AndAnotherModule());
}
install(module);
```

Or, if you want to use configuration from another guice binding:

```
// In SomeOtherModule
@Provides @FromSomeOtherModule
public XYZ getXYZ() { ... }

// In AndAnotherModule
@Provides @FromAndAnotherModule
public XYZ getXYZ() { ... }

// In a module which "picks" between the two:
@ProvidesIntoOptional(ProvidesIntoOptional.Type.DEFAULT)
public XYZ provideBasedOnCondition(
    @SomeQualifier boolean condition,
    @FromSomeOtherModule XYZ fromSomeOtherModule,
    @FromAndAnotherModule XYZ fromAndOtherModule) {
  return condition ? fromSomeOtherModule : fromAndOtherModule;
}
```

where `@FromSomeOtherModule`, `@FromAndAnotherModule` and `@SomeQualifier` are suitable binding annotations.

Comment: I can get that condition only in config which is created after Modules are installed. 
1. can I install another module module after     Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new SomeModule()); is created?

Comment: Thanks. let me try your new suggestions.

Comment: Given the question, I believe the override is the best solution.

Comment: For config we are using netflix archaius

import com.netflix.archaius.api.annotations.DefaultValue;
import com.netflix.archaius.api.annotations.PropertyName;
public interface Config {

    @PropertyName(name = "useMockResource")
    @DefaultValue("false")
    boolean useMockResource


This gets created only after injector is created. i don't want to create another property loader. Any suggestions on how can I work around this egg first or chicken first issue.